# How to conditionally install and ship files in yocto bb recipe?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

My yocto build/conf/auto.conf file contains a variable :

```
READ_ONLY_FS ?= "true"
```

I want to install a configuration file that can be modified, for that I want that if READ_ONLY_FS is "true", my.conf file is directly installed in /etc. But if READ_ONLY_FS is "false", I want that my.conf file is installed in /data/etc and then soft linked to /etc. (/data is a read write partition)

Currently my recipe contains this as an attempt to achieve what I wanted:

```sh
FILES_${PN} += " ${@bb.utils.contains('READ_ONLY_FS', 'true', '', '/data/${sysconfdir}/my.conf', d)}"

do_install_append() {
    install -d ${D}/${sysconfdir}
    if [ "${@bb.utils.contains('READ_ONLY_FS', 'true', 'true', 'false', d)} == "true" ]; then
        install -d ${D}/data/${sysconfdir}
        install -m 0755 ${S}/my.conf ${D}/data/${sysconfdir}/my.conf
        ln -sf ${D}/data/${sysconfdir}/my.conf ${D}/${sysconfdir}/my.conf
    else
        install -m 0755 ${S}/my.conf ${D}/${sysconfdir}/my.conf
    fi    
}
```

But I get an error: Files/directories were installed but not shipped. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I typically create a bbappend in my own layer to append to volatile-binds.bb,
eg: `meta-mylayer/recipes-core/volatile-binds/volatile-binds.bbappend` contains

```
VOLATILE_BINDS += "\
    /data/${sysconfdir}/my.conf /${sysconfdir}/my.conf\n\
"
```

I have to ensure my rootfs pulls in the `volatile-binds` package via a package-group or `IMAGE_INSTALL`.

The recipe installing `my.conf` does not need to be aware of this redirection, just install into `${sysconfdir}/my.conf`.

`volatile-binds` generates a startup script that only takes action if `${sysconfdir}/my.conf` is read-only. In that case it will copy `${sysconfdir}/my.conf` to `/data/${sysconfdir}/my.conf` (if it doesn't exist there yet) and bind-mount the latter on top of the former.

I use

```
IMAGE_FEATURES += "read-only-rootfs"
```

in my 'read-only image' recipe.

Answer (score 1):

Bitbake should normally tell you which files were "installed but not shipped". In your case it seems, that you install `/data/${sysconfdir}/my.conf` and the symlink at `/${sysconfdir}/my.conf`, but only add the former path to `FILES`.

BTW: I think, you can simplify your code by removing the condition in your assignment of `FILES` and by accessing `READ_ONLY_FS` directly.

Something like this should work (not tested at all):

```
FILES_${PN} += "/data/${sysconfdir}/my.conf /${sysconfdir}/my.conf"

do_install_append() {
    install -d ${D}/${sysconfdir}
    if [ ${READ_ONLY_FS} == "true" ]; then
        install -d ${D}/data/${sysconfdir}
        install -m 0755 ${S}/my.conf ${D}/data/${sysconfdir}/my.conf
        ln -sf ${D}/data/${sysconfdir}/my.conf ${D}/${sysconfdir}/my.conf
    else
        install -m 0755 ${S}/my.conf ${D}/${sysconfdir}/my.conf
    fi    
}
```

Comment: But if it has FILES_${PN} += " /data/${sysconfdir}/my.conf " and READ_ONLY_FS is false, then, would not it expect a /data/etc/my.conf that will not be installed?

Comment: No it's the other way round. You install the files you need in `do_install` and all of them need to be shipped in some package by adding he paths to `FILES`. As far as I remember it is not a problem to have additional paths in `FILES` that are not actually installed, but I might be wrong.